# How to get all the songs of a particular artists using restapi in deezer

Tags: deezer

I am trying to get all the songs of a particular artists using deezer restapi using python.

There seems to be no api for the same. Can I only get the top songs from a particular artist ?

Is there any api supported to get all the songs of a particular artist.

Comment: Did you find a suitable solution for this problem? I'm also interested in fetching ALL songs of an artist, even if it's 10000 songs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get all the top songs of an artist with the /artist/{artistId}/top endpoint, described here: http://developers.deezer.com/api/artist/top

You will just have to use the "limit" parameter so you can retrieve the count of songs that you would want.

Comment: Can bpm information be provided in the result of http://developers.deezer.com/api/artist/top api..

Comment: No you have to retrieve it with a request to api.deezer.com/track/{id}

Comment: It seems like the backend limit is fixed to 100, even if you fetch with `?limit=1000`